# Android developer beginner

Tags: android

Hi I have been programming with Java for a while and now I want to learn Android development.There are plenty of books and I myself have bought one 4 months ago but dident have time to read it and now while surfing the internet I found that at the end of 2011 android 4.0 was released and thee book I have covers android 3.0.

This is the book I have:
 Pro Android 3

What I wanted to ask is if this is a good book for a beginner android developer and if not pls recommend a better one and if I shoud get a book for android 4.0 so I dont get confused in diferent types of android versions development?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114287/good-book-for-beginning-android-development

Comment: Pick up professional Android 4, great book to get up and go.

Comment: Guys Please help a newcomer .Dont discourage them with negative votes.Its better to give a link than downvoting.

Comment: i have also asked questions like this when beginning programming a new language, but they are closed before downvoting.//(ㄒoㄒ)//

Comment: only problem is that the book Professional android 4 hasent been released yet and the previous verion was for android 2 witch is a bit outdated I think

Comment: For Your kind information most of the devices are still running on 2.x version.android 4 is just an advanced version.That does not make 2.x outdated It is still more popular.

Answer (score 2):

Such Questions have already been asked on SO.Pro Android3 is a better among all the books I have read.And you can also refer to Reito Meier book as well as Begining Android. These books are the best books.These are the basics for android ,you will not get confused.Instead it will make your base strong.And always Be in touch with android developer site.Its better to concentrate on one book and visit [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) to clear all your doubts.
Best of Luck for Your Future.Guys Please help a newcomer .Dont discourage them with negative votes.Its better to give a link than downvoting.

Comment: This and if you go the the Android info section on SO you also get additional information like books and resources. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info

Comment: Can you pleaca tell me if it will be a problem if I learn to deveop appications for android 3 instead of 4 (I mean if android 3 is considered outdated) and if what I build will also work on android 4

Answer (score 0):

read mark murphy books and then go android market and do some small application your own.
if you know java so you can easily comfortable with android within 1 month.

all the best...

Comment: so is it a problem if I learn android development 3 first or should I try and learn for 4 first now that it's out?

Answer (score 0):

Last month I had an examination on Android at university and I also asked the same question to myself. And after a few weeks of reading I think the best "book" (even if it is not a book) is the official Android-developer website. The webmasters restructured it and now it is much better than any book I read. It gives short on-point descriptions on any topic of the android-development. In your case I would start at this ponit: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html